# log website visits to CSV file?

Tags: browser, logging, csv

I'd like to log my website visits throughout the day.  i use several browsers on several computers.  I'm thinking that one way to do this would be to write website visit data to a CSV file stored in Dropbox.  I'd like for it to record which computer it was, date and time of visit, url, and title.  Is there a utility that will do this for me?

Comment: Are you looking to keep track of every site that you visit or perhaps looking to have some reference to look back at later to find a site that you looked at X days ago and want to look at again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google History](https://www.google.com/history/) works pretty well.  Well, maybe not logged to CSV.  But, it may give you some alternative ideas.

Comment: I looked at the FAQ and don't understand why my question was closed as off-topic.  Could somebody enlighten me?